# Modify elements of an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

For the below code, I was hoping that elements of my arraylist would be modified but its not. How can I modify the elements

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ArrayList<String> aList = new ArrayList<>();
        aList .add("aa");
        aList .add("bb");
        aList .add("cc");

        new Main().modifyList(aList );
        for(String s: aList ){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    public void modifyList(ArrayList<String> aList ){
        for(String s: aList){
            System.out.println(s);
            s = s + "ss";
        }
    }
}
```

Its printing 
aa 
bb 
cc 
aa 
bb 
cc

Expected output 
aa 
bb 
cc 
aass 
bbss 
ccss

Comment: @MichalKordas You modified the code so it doesn't compile. Edit rolled back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void modifyList(ArrayList<String> aList ){
        for(String s: aList){
            System.out.println(s);
            s = s + "ss";
        }
    }
```

Strings are immutable.  So when you change `s` you are creating a new object that is different than the one in the ArrayList.

So you need to iterate over the array and replace the old value with the new using the `set` method.

```
for (int i = 0; i < alist.size(); i++) {
     String s = aList.get(i) + "ss";
     aList.set(i, s);
}
```

To simply append the changes do the following:

```
int len = alist.size();
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
     String s = aList.get(i) + "ss";
     aList.add(s);
}
```

Prints

> aa bb cc aass bbss ccss

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I created a simple class of Employee with a name and was able to change the name of employees.

Comment: @user2532244 I modified my answer to reflect your edit.

Comment: Using an `i` loop is bad for performance if the method is ever modified to accept any type of `List` and called with e.g. a `LinkedList`. [Using an iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61020829/5221149) is preferable to help future-proof the code.

Answer (score 1):

`s = s + "ss"` only updates the local variable `s`, it doesn't update the list.

If you want to update elements in a list, use a [`ListIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) and the [`set()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#set-E-) method:

```
public static void modifyList(List<String> aList) {
    for (ListIterator<String> iter = aList.listIterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
        String s = iter.next();
        s = s + "ss";
        iter.set(s); // replace element in the list with new value
    }
}
```

In Java 8+, you can use a *lambda expression* with the [`replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-) method:

```
public static void modifyList(List<String> aList) {
    aList.replaceAll(s -> s + "ss");
}
```

Both will perform well even if the list doesn't handle random access well, e.g. if the list is a [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

*Test*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> aList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("aa", "bb", "cc"));
    modifyList(aList);
    System.out.println(aList);
}
```

*Output*

```
[aass, bbss, ccss]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem, the variable `s` is unused and visible only in the scope of the for-loop:

```
for (String s: aList) {
    System.out.println(s);
    s = s + "ss";           // the variable 's' is unused
}
```

Either use `List::set` to replace the current value:

```
for (int i=0; i<aList.size(); i++) {
    String s = aList.get(i);
    System.out.println(s);
    aList.set(i, s + "ss");
}
```

... or use the advantage of [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream) as of [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) and map the list to a new one:

```
List<String> newList = aList.stream()
                            .map(s -> s + "ss")
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: If you're going to use Java 8 features, you should still stick within the requirements of the question, i.e. updating the existing list, which is easy [using the `replaceAll()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61020829/5221149).

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this, you need to update each element as follows:

```
public void modifyList(ArrayList<String> aList){
        for(int i = 0; i < aList.size(); i++){
            String s = aList.get(i);
            aList.set(i, s+"ss");
        }
}
```

Comment: Don't know why this got down-voted, but my guess is that it's because this answer don't *explain* anything, i.e. why the question code doesn't work.

Comment: Using an `i` loop is bad for performance if the method is ever modified to accept any type of `List` and called with e.g. a `LinkedList`. [Using an iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61020829/5221149) is preferable to help future-proof the code.